# d3.js line chart - updating the points values

Tags: javascript, d3.js

How i can execute this code repetitively with a interval of 1 sec? The idea is update a d3.js line chart and move (smooth) the points in y axis of the chart.

Add line with random data:

```
var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;    

    data =  [
        [{'x':0,'y':0},{'x':5,'y':0},{'x':10,'y':0},{'x':15,'y':3},{'x':20,'y':7},{'x':25,'y': randomNumber}]
    ];       

    var path = svg.selectAll('.d3-line')
        .data(data)
        .enter()
        .append("path")
            .attr("d", line)
            .attr("class", "d3-line d3-line-medium")
            .style('stroke-width', 3)
            .style('stroke', function(d,i){      
                return colors[i%colors.length];
            });
```

Add points of the line:

```
// Group dots
    var points = svg.selectAll('.d3-dots')
        .data(data)
        .enter()
        .append("g")
            .attr("class", "d3-dots");


    // Add dots
    points.selectAll('.d3-dot')
        .data(function(d, index) {     
            var a = [];
            d.forEach(function(point,i) {
                a.push({'index': index, 'point': point});
            });   
            return a;
        })
        .enter()
        .append('circle')
            .attr('class', 'd3-dot')
            .attr("r", 0)
            .attr("transform", function(d) { 
                return "translate(" + x(d.point.x) + "," + y(d.point.y) + ")"; }
            )
            .style("fill", "#fff")
            .style("stroke-width", 0)
            .style('stroke', function(d,i){  
                return colors[d.index%colors.length];
            })  
            .style("cursor", "pointer");
```

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your code to give `line chart a smooth transition`:

`First add an id to the line as stated below:`

```
var path = svg.selectAll('.d3-line')
        .data(data)
        .enter()
        .append("path")
            .attr("id", function(d,i){ return "line"+i;})
            .attr("d", line)
            .attr("class", "d3-line d3-line-medium")
            .style('stroke-width', 3)
            .style('stroke', function(d,i){      
                return colors[i%colors.length];
            });
```

`Following the above code add this below snippet:`

```
d3.selectAll(".line").each(function(d,i){

                    // Get the length of each line in turn
                    var totalLength = d3.select("#line"+i).node().getTotalLength();
                        d3.select("#line"+i).attr("stroke-dasharray", totalLength + " " + totalLength)
                          .attr("stroke-dashoffset", totalLength)
                          .transition()
                          .duration(2000)
                          .delay(100*i)
                          .ease("linear") //linear, quad, bounce... other examples here - http://bl.ocks.org/hunzy/9929724
                          .attr("stroke-dashoffset", 0);
                        //  .style("stroke-width",3)
                    });
```

Comment: I did that you said and keep not working. I replace the code and nothing!

My ideia is move the points of line with smooth move in y axis.

line chart with line: oi68.tinypic.com/344eebm.jpg

Comment: Do you want my all source code to analize? Sorry the insistence but this is for college work

Comment: It would definitely work . Please care to look at this example where I have followed same approach with transition (http://jsbin.com/baqaki/edit?js,output).

Comment: This isn't the idea. I want that line bends in y axis. Imagine on the last straight line, this one bends up and down.

The effect is represent one bending blade(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I2Ajiz__ww0)

Comment: is there any other figure of line chart that would best describe your need

Comment: http://oi68.tinypic.com/344eebm.jpg

This is my chart and i want move the pit of line